# How to get all CPU cache information without root access

Tags: cpu, cache, cpu-architecture, dmidecode

I am trying to find out the cache mapping scheme for all the levels of class of a Linux server, including associativity, however I do not have root access. I would just use `dmidecode` for this but you need root access. Is there another way of getting the same information without root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lscpu`, in `util-linux`, describes the cache layout without requiring `root`:

```
[...]
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
```

The files in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cache/` should contain all the information you’re looking for, including associativity, and are readable without being `root`, but they’re a little harder to parse:

```
grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cache/index*/*
```

(I got this from [Where is the L1 memory cache of Intel x86 processors documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/716145/4500798))